# Test Settings option is not missing in visual studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, selenium, visual-studio-2013, nunit

I am trying to add test settings file using this [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx). 
but when i try to add new item, i didn't find Test Settings option.

[image: Here is the screen shor]

please help me to solve this

Answer (score 1):

Things have changed, VS2013 (and 2015) generally do not use a `.testsettings` file any more.

See *[Specifying Test Settings for Visual Studio Tests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)*.

Comment: then how can change settings for parallel execution of testcases?

Comment: @AhmadAbbasi Read the linked page: it shows how to add a `.testsettings`. ("Generally do not use" does not mean you cannot have one.)